# Alembic: How to migrate custom type in a model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

My `User` model is

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # noinspection PyShadowingBuiltins
    uuid = Column('uuid', GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                  unique=True)
    email = Column('email', String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    _password = Column('password', String, nullable=False)
    created_on = Column('created_on', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        default=datetime.utcnow())
    last_login = Column('last_login', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        onupdate=datetime.utcnow())
```

where `GUID` is a custom type as described in [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) (Exactly same)

Now when I run

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added initial table"
```

I get my `upgrade()` as

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('users',
    sa.Column('uuid', sa.GUID(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('password', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('last_login', sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('uuid'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('email'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('uuid')
    )
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

but during applying upgrade -> `alembic upgrade head`, I see

```
File "alembic/versions/49cc74d0da9d_added_initial_table.py", line 20, in upgrade
    sa.Column('uuid', sa.GUID(), nullable=False),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GUID'
```

How can I make it work with `GUID`/custom type here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace `sa.GUID()` with either `sa.CHAR(32)` or `UUID()` (after adding the import line `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID`) depending on the dialect.

Replacing it with `GUID()` (after adding the import line `from your.models.custom_types import GUID`) will work also, but then the upgrade script is tied to your model code, which may not be a good thing.

Comment: but that would break in tests if I am using `sqlite` plus it wont be consistent, isn't it?

Comment: I really don't care much for using `sqlite` in tests, since the test environment should closely follow the production. Other than that, are you deploying the same code against more than one dialects?

Comment: Anyway, I would want the migration scripts to be consistent with the actual schema at the point of time, consistency with the code be damned since the code is forever changing.

Comment: I would think I would care for sqlite for my tests since they can be run  in-memory, but what you said also makes a valid point, let me try what you said and reply you

Comment: I agree with you completely and have PostgreSQL for both `dev` and `test` environments and your answer helped me a lot @sayap. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helps. We should all just be grateful that we got the amazing alembic library without having to sponsor some kickstarter campaign, like what the Django guys did :P

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it like follows:

Let's assume you have the following module `my_guid`, containing (from the page you already cited, with minor naming modifications):

```
import uuid as uuid_package
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID as PG_UUID
from sqlalchemy import TypeDecorator, CHAR

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    impl = CHAR

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(PG_UUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid_package.UUID):
                return "%.32x" % uuid_package.UUID(value)
            else:
                # hexstring
                return "%.32x" % value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid_package.UUID(value)
```

If you use this GUID in your models, you just need to add three lines at `alembic/env.py`:

```
from my_guid import GUID
import sqlalchemy as sa
sa.GUID = GUID
```

That worked for me. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer** (using sqlalchemy version `1.4.25`):

From the [documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#controlling-the-module-prefix):

> For user-defined types, that is, any custom type that is not within
> the sqlalchemy. module namespace, by default Alembic will use the
> value of __module__ for the custom type:
>
> ```py
> Column("my_column", myapp.models.utils.types.MyCustomType())
> ```
>
> The imports for the above type again must be made present within
> the migration, either manually, or by adding it to script.py.mako.

So, import your `my_module` in `script.py.mako` (and you probably need to define your custom type in a file other than `models.py`):

```
...
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import my_module
${imports if imports else ""}
...
```

**Long answer**:

I have my custom type `BinaryUUID` defined in `uuid_type_mysql.py` and I'm importing it in `models.py` and using it there:

`models.py`:

```py
...
from .uuid_type_mysql import BinaryUUID
...
```

After generating the migrations with `flask db migrate` I would get this on the migration file:

```py
...
sa.Column('public_id', my_module.uuid_type_mysql.BinaryUUID(length=16), nullable=False),
...
```

And the problem is that the migration does not know `my_module` because it is not imported.

After adding `import my_module` to `script.py.mako` as suggested in the documentation, now the module is imported in the migration file:

```py
...
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import my_module
...
```

After this, everything work fine for me with the bonus that it is not needed to manually edit the generated migration.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses `sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid.UUIDType`, which uses `CHAR(32)` or `BINARY(16)` to represent the UUID if you are on a database without a `UUID` type. You need to account for this in your migration, which must create a `CHAR(32)/BINARY(16)` on a DB without a `UUID` type and a `UUIDType` on databases with it.

My SQLAlchemy class looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid import UUIDType
from sqlalchemy import CHAR, Column, Integer

Base = declarative_base()

def get_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

class Dashboard(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dashboards'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), default=get_uuid)
```

and the actual batch operation looks like this (which supports SQLite, MySQL and Postgres):

```py
from superset import db # Sets up a SQLAlchemy connection

def upgrade():
    bind = op.get_bind()
    session = db.Session(bind=bind)
    db_type = session.bind.dialect.name

    def add_uuid_column(col_name, _type):
        """Add a uuid column to a given table"""
        with op.batch_alter_table(col_name) as batch_op:
            batch_op.add_column(Column('uuid', UUIDType(binary=False), default=get_uuid))
        for s in session.query(_type):
            s.uuid = get_uuid()
            session.merge(s)

        if db_type != 'postgresql':
            with op.batch_alter_table(col_name) as batch_op:
                batch_op.alter_column('uuid', existing_type=CHAR(32),
                                      new_column_name='uuid', nullable=False)
                batch_op.create_unique_constraint('uq_uuid', ['uuid'])

        session.commit()

add_uuid_column('dashboards', Dashboard)
session.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't help me, the resulting migration has app.models.CHAR instead of app.models.GUID where we still need to manually import app.models. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Following-up on the solution from [@Red-Tune-84](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810638/11372523)

```
class GUID(types.TypeDecorator)
  impl = CHAR

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.impl.__repr__()

  # You type logic here.
```

does work but you might need in parallel to set in `env.py` the configuration `user_module_prefix`.

For instance, with `context.configure(..., user_module_prefix="sa.")`, the type above will appear as `sa.CHAR(...)` in the alembic migration.

Comment: This was a key solution for me. In my case the problem was that the rendered `Column` migration was my `TypeDecorator` rather than the underlying PostgreSQL type with the appropriate arguments. Adding the `__repr__` override fixed that. In addition, I need to make sure my root package was imported in my `script.py.mako`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `__repr__` function of the `impl` attribute class worked for me for most custom types.  I find it cleaner to have the migration definition contained inside class instead worrying about putting imports in your `env.py` or `scripts.py.mako`.  Plus, it makes it easy to move your code between modules.

```
Class GUID(types.TypeDecorator)
    impl = CHAR

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.impl.__repr__()

    # You type logic here.
```

The automigration will produce `CHAR(length=XXX)`.

Comment: I don't think this works alone, at least with Alembic 1.4.3 and SQLAlchemy ORM. Assuming your custom types are defined or imported in `app.models`. The resulting migration will just have `app.models.CHAR` instead of `app.models.GUID`. Maybe the default rendering changed since this answer?